# How to perform tests regarding Facebook Pages Search API using Graph API explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am planning to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/search-pages/ API in my application to let users know if their business details are wrong on Facebook. Asking them to login into Facebook is out of the question. Before Development I was a planning to use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ for testing this API's capabilities.

The problem I am facing is that it doesn't even allow me to test this API. I am getting this message -

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AALuCyUt_QOPCdPi-sxR8ZJ"
  }
}
```

My question is

1.) Is there any way to test this API before going through App review process for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference#page-public-metadata-access permission.

2.)For going through Page Public metadata access app review process , its requirements mentions sharing screencast showing end-to-end user experience [image]

How to do this when you are just at the first step of testing API?